# Cannot change text in Switch

Tags: java, android

I have a Switch in my project which I want to change the text depends on when it 's ON or OFF. I have also a Toast Event which is change text successfully, but I have problem with the Switch Text. If you can help me I will appreciate.

```
toggleTraceBtn = new Switch(getActivity());
    toggleTraceBtn.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding_huge), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding_normal),
            (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding_medium), toggleTraceBtn.getPaddingBottom());
    refreshTraceBtn();

    toggleTraceBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener((toggleButton, isChecked) -> {
        if (isChecked) {
            performanceTracker.initialize(true);
        } else {
            performanceTracker.stop();
        }
    });
```

This is the Switch Button and I Check when its ON and when its OFF. If its ON, goes to initialize in class performanceTracer doing some stuff, and then goes to refreshTraceBtn() which is the method is doing the set Text.

```
private void refreshTraceBtn() {
    toggleTraceBtn.setText(performanceTracker.printState());
    toggleTraceBtn.setChecked(performanceTracker.isEnabled());
}
```

PrintState is the method I take the text. Takes the text normally but Switch text does not change. Any suggestions ?

Update: sometimes I take this Exception but not always.

```
    W/System.err: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@a5a1621 is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:679)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:459)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.handleMessage(Toast.java:342)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: yes but I don 't take any exception. The only problem I see is that when refreshTraceBtn() is called, it 's passing the setText and setChecked twice

Comment: what does debugging have to do with exceptions being thrown? I'm merely asking whether you checked whether or not the code you think is being executed is being executed and on/with the values you think it is

Comment: Yes I checked that and the values that its take are the correct, the only problem is that the  set Text never change the Switch text

Comment: I believe that the problem is in setChecked which is make the button enable and in If statement which checks if it is enable

Comment: might be because you have several instances of toggleTraceBtn, and you are updating the wrong one

Comment: Yea but I am not sure what I have to do now. Ι appreciate your help

Comment: you will need to debug and check the rest of your code to figure out what is going wrong

Comment: After your `if / else` block in the listener, try calling `refreshTraceBtn()` again

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fix the issue and this is the solution:
In method setOnCheckedChangeListener() the method give as a parameter toggleButton and isChecked. The toggleButton that it give as is not the same with the one that we made (toggleTraceBtn). So program give the set Text to another Button which covers ours. So I had to say that `toggleTraceBtn = toggleButton;`
***Thanks for your help!!***